# Custom tab only for specific category – Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4, tabs

I created a custom tab for frontend with the following code:

```
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description"
           name="tab"
           template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom.phtml"
           group="detailed_info">
        <arguments>
           ...
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

in catalog_product_view.xml

Now I would like to show the tab only for products that have a specific attribute set or belong to a specific category. Is it possible to implement this issue in M2.4.2?

Comment: are you looking for frontend?

Comment: Yes, for frontend – I just update the question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**catalog_product_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View"
                   name="custom_tab.tab"
                   template="Vendor_Module::custom_tab.phtml"
                   group="detailed_info">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="sort_order" xsi:type="string">40</argument>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Custom Tab</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Vendor/Module/view/templates/custom_tab.phtml**

```
<?php $categoryId = 3; ?> //category id to check in current product assign this category or not
<?php if(in_array("3",$this->getProduct()->getCategoryIds())): ?> //check in product category ids array
    <?php echo "Tab is Show" ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rk Rahod I managed to create this solution – works like a charm:

**Vendor/Module/view/templates/custom_tab.phtml**

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->registry('current_product');
// Get all categories
$categories = $product->getCategoryIds();
// Define target category
$targetCategory = 90;
// Check if target categoy is in the category list
if(in_array($targetCategory,$categories)): ?>
   <?php echo "Tab is shown" ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: i think product object get in $block->getProduct()

Comment: so no need to get a current product